# Converting String binary literal into Integer [Java]

Tags: java, string, integer

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    String s = "0b00110001";
    i = Integer.decode(s);
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Comment: You have `Integer.parseInt()` to do stuff like this

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar that won't work without string manipulation

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar You are mistaken.

Comment: @Alexander - Please elaborate the question then :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Look at the String closely. Trying Integer.parseInt() will throw an exception.

Comment: @Alexander -I saw the "b" there, If you have your own way of encoding numbers, you will have to write your own code to decode them. What are you expecting?. What should be the output?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar It's not custom encoding. It's binary. Try `System.out.println(0b00110001)`, it will print 49.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak That works but I am really trying to see if I can pass the String to an int.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - The compiler replaces `0b00110001` with 49. Java code (for `parseInt()` ) doesn't understand this format

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar - that's right. @Alexander Why do you have such string? Could the string not be just `"00110001"`?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - He could achieve the same result by removing the "0b" part from the String :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar That would be the only way to do this? as in Andy's answer?

Comment: @Alexander - Probably yes.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar True, but then if some component sends a binary number without "0b" prefix, you will strip off two first bits. So you would have to check what are the first two characters, so complexity goes up.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - Of course.  He will have to have that check

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I can assume for this that it will always have the same two leading chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strip off the leading 2 characters and use `Integer.parseInt`:

```
Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2), 2);
```

You probably need some check that it does actually start with `0b`.